Angular CSS: Expansion panel and align items at the top despite the status
I am coding some own expansion panel in Angular. I want to mimic the behaviour of Angular Material Expansion Panel (which won't work with my requirement).
So, I have essentially 3 items, namely

a starting icon
text
a collapse/expand button.

When I click on the expand icon the text is displayed. The running code is provided on Stackblitz.
When the panel is collapsed all the three icons are on the same level

This is due to the
    align-items: center;

and this looks perfectly. As soon as I expand the  panel the icons float as well to the center of the container. Is there a way to fixate them on the top AND have it centered when collapsed?

The only idea I had was to wrap everything in divs and play a little with flexbox. Main change was to wrap icon & button into div with hardcoded height. Not perfect, but result is as expected (just needs pixel adjustments).
stackblitz

Wrapping an additional container looks great. Just a side note: The class name container MIGHT  get in conflict with default bootstrap class names. But anyway your idea helps and thx.

yeah, you're right :)
